# Can't delete app because it isn't there

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have an LG L70 and was downloading an app that was about 470 megabytes and then i got a notification saying that there wasn't enough space on the phone to download it so i clicked it and it looked like it wasn't installed. I checked the memory on the phone and the app wasn't there. Did the phone download the some of the app but not finish and still keep the app? Because it still took all the space but it isn't there. I want to delete it but don't know how.

Comment: Most likely the "partly download" still sticks around somewhere. Usually in `/data/local`, where you might wish to explore with e.g. a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Settings -> Application manager -> All and search for Download Manager. Click on it and then click on Clear Data.